# How Django fills Model instance?

Tags: django

It's interesting how Django fills Model instance with values from database?

Let's imagine we have model:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField("date published")
```

When I did some research on Django source code I met descriptor DeferredAttribute in model fields https://github.com/django/django/blob/68912e4f6f84f21322f92a2c7b6c77f68f91b9c9/django/db/models/query_utils.py#L155. I can see there is `__get__` magic method. But no `__set__`.

Does Django fills directly `__dict__` of Model instance or how? Could you please explain the process from request (`q = Question.objects.get(id=1)`) to instance manipulation like `print(q.question_text)`?

Comment: It works with a `ModelState`.